# Fractional Number.

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

how to fix this error. . when user input whole number and multipy it there's no problem in this part of my code

but when user input a fractional number(negative or positive) like "1/2,-2/3 ETC" there is an error

the error  is pointing in: new1 = CDbl(txta1.Text) * CDbl(txtb2.Text) * CDbl(txtc3.Text)

Error Message: Conversion from string "1/2" to type 'Double' is not valid.

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Dim new1, new2, new3, new4, new5, new6, add1, add2, minus1 As Double

```
    new1 = CDbl(txta1.Text) * CDbl(txtb2.Text) * CDbl(txtc3.Text)  
    new2 = CDbl(txta2.Text) * CDbl(txtb3.Text) * CDbl(txtc1.Text)  
    new3 = CDbl(txta3.Text) * CDbl(txtb1.Text) * CDbl(txtc2.Text)  

    new4 = CDbl(txtc1.Text) * CDbl(txtb2.Text) * CDbl(txta3.Text)  
    new5 = CDbl(txtc2.Text) * CDbl(txtb3.Text) * CDbl(txta1.Text)  
    new6 = CDbl(txtc3.Text) * CDbl(txtb1.Text) * CDbl(txta2.Text)
```

Comment: 1/2 is not actually a number, it's a representation of a number which is 0.5 You can't convert 1/2 directly to a double. Add a bit of text on your UI asking the user to write 0.5 or else you'll have to add code to specifically parse fractions.

Comment: what if user input. . 26/2 ETC. . how can i convert it to a whole number. . or how can i detect if user input 1/2 and then the program will convert it in 0.5 or what ever user input a fractional number

Answer (score 5):

Please activate Option strict ON, which will help you to prevent rookie mistakes like trying to use a textfield like txta1.text as a number: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329
You have to try to parse a value from text to a number like so:

```
Dim number1 As Double

If Double.TryParse(txta1.Text, number1) Then
 // do something
Else
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of a Double.", _
                   value)
// report error
End If
```

Otherwise it is very hard to debug your code.
As to fractions: I would be very hard to parse a fraction reliably by hand. I would somethink prebuild, like a mathematic expression library. Take a look: https://ncalc.codeplex.com/

Comment: if i rebuild this. . i would not meet the deadline of this project. . the link that you shared is new to me so i need to study it first before applying in my codes and it took's me an hours or even a day to understand it  T_T

Comment: What you have build WILL fail in production. So bugfix this and be faster in the long run.

Comment: this is bad i don't know what do to right now. . i'm  losing idea's how to fix this . . :/

Comment: @user3839017 I would try to understand the Double.TryParse() pattern first. It is easy to implement and handles 90% of the maintenance problems. if need be, ship now and tell them "fractions are coming in a few days".

Then work on the fraction, it's probably very simply if you are using nuget to install ncalc / similar libraries. Extend your solution so it can handle the fractions. Be done.

Answer (score 2):

"1/2" is a string and must be parsed and converted into a numeric by your code.

Here is an example. 
For use with simple fractions (as shown in your example), decimals and negative numbers.

Note: You should add error checking. For brevity, I did not include any error checking.

```
    Dim strInput As String = "-1/2"
    Dim dblValue As Double = Nothing

    If strInput.Contains("/") Then ' A fraction
        Dim strArray() As String = strInput.Split(CChar("/"))
        dblValue = CDbl(strArray(0)) / CDbl(strArray(1))
    Else
        dblValue = CDbl(strInput)
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(dblValue)
```

Comment: "1/2" is a sample input of a user. .  user can input whole number(positive or negative), decimal "." and fractional number (positive or negative). .

Comment: @user3839017 Sample imput is nice, if you can control the source. E.g. it's a database. A human WILL enter invalid or malformed input. He will accidentally enter 1/8i (wrong key press). He will try to enter 1,234,00.11 etc. pp.
First rule of UI design: User will enter everything.

Comment: i have a validation that user can't enter any letter or any character except in "0"to"9"(ok in anywhere)  "-"('only one allowed, only as 1st char)  "."(only one allowed, anywhere, not if / exists) "/"('only one allowed, not if . exists, not as 1st char, not after '-')